# Disk IO causing high load on Xen/CentOS guest

Tags: centos, virtualization, xen, blocking

### Background

I'm having serious issues with a xen based server, this is on the guest partition. It's a paravirtualized CentOS 5.5. I'm not sure if it's hardware or software related, or in between (drivers).

**Basic information**

Updated controller firmware (this was done as the last step)

```
Smart Array 6i in Slot 0
   Hardware Revision: Rev B
   Firmware Version: 2.84
```

Updated kernel

```
Linux domU 2.6.18-194.32.1.el5xen #1 SMP Wed Jan 5 19:32:33 EST 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux
```

**The problem is in disk write speed.**

Baseline performance is

- dom0 ~30MB/s
- domU ~4MB/s (small files)
- domU ~1.5MB/s (large files)

The following numbers are taken from top while copying a large file over the network.

If i copy the file another time the speed decreases in relation to load average. So the second time it's half the speed of the first time.

It needs some time to cool off after this. Load average slowly decreases until it's once again usable. `ls /` takes about 30 seconds.

```
top - 13:26:44 up 13 days, 21:44,  2 users,  load average: 7.03, 5.08, 3.15
Tasks: 134 total,   2 running, 132 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.0%us,  0.1%sy,  0.0%ni, 25.3%id, 74.5%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.1%st
Mem:   1048752k total,  1041460k used,     7292k free,     3116k buffers
Swap:  2129912k total,       40k used,  2129872k free,   904740k cached

  PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
 1506 root      10  -5     0    0    0 S  0.3  0.0   0:03.94 cifsd
    1 root      15   0  2172  644  556 S  0.0  0.1   0:00.08 init
```

Meanwhile the host is ~0.5 load avg and steady over time. ~50% wait

Server hardware is dual xeon, 3gb ram, 170gb scsi 320 10k rpm, and shouldn't have any problems with copying files over the network.

```
disk = [ "tap:aio:/vm/domU.img,xvda,w" ]
```

I also get these in the log

```
INFO: task syslogd:1350 blocked for more than 120 seconds.
"echo 0 > /proc/sys/kernel/hung_task_timeout_secs" disables this message.
syslogd       D 00062E4F  2208  1350      1          1353  1312 (NOTLB)
       c0ef0ed0 00000286 6e71a411 00062e4f c0ef0f18 00000009 c0f20000 6e738bfd
       00062e4f 0001e7ec c0f2010c c181a724 c1abd200 00000000 ffffffff c0ef0ecc
       c041a180 00000000 c0ef0ed8 c03d6a50 00000000 00000000 c03d6a00 00000000
Call Trace:
 [<c041a180>] __wake_up+0x2a/0x3d
 [<ee06a1ea>] log_wait_commit+0x80/0xc7 [jbd]
 [<c043128b>] autoremove_wake_function+0x0/0x2d
 [<ee065661>] journal_stop+0x195/0x1ba [jbd]
 [<c0490a32>] __writeback_single_inode+0x1a3/0x2af
 [<c04568ea>] do_writepages+0x2b/0x32
 [<c045239b>] __filemap_fdatawrite_range+0x66/0x72
 [<c04910ce>] sync_inode+0x19/0x24
 [<ee09b007>] ext3_sync_file+0xaf/0xc4 [ext3]
 [<c047426f>] do_fsync+0x41/0x83
 [<c04742ce>] __do_fsync+0x1d/0x2b
 [<c0405413>] syscall_call+0x7/0xb
 =======================
```

I have tried disabling irqbalanced as suggested [here](http://140.211.166.79/mailarchive/linux-kernel/2010/9/3/4615243) but it does not seem to make any difference.

**Updates:**

```
domU# cat /sys/block/xvda/queue/scheduler
[noop] anticipatory deadline cfq
```

Copying files from/to the disk causes load to remain < 4. Subsequent copying causes load to increase.
Copying files over the network causes load > 4 in the first run, subsequent copying causes the server to halt almost completely, demanding time to cool off, it never goes down, just give it 10-15 mins to get back up. But it's really not viable for a server to behave like that.

The network traffic is in itself not causing any trouble running iperf for instance does not produce any measurable effect. Reported bandwidth is > 1gbit.

Write performance on dom0 is OK

```
dom0# dd if=/dev/zero of=./test1024M bs=1024k count=1024 conv=fsync
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 34.9725 seconds, 30.7 MB/s
```

Write performance on domU is sluggish

```
domU# dd if=/dev/zero of=./test1024M bs=1024k count=1024 conv=fsync
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 622.163 seconds, 1.7 MB/s
```

**This is ~95% performance loss.**

Read performance is OK

```
dom0# hdparm -tT /dev/cciss/c0d0p1

/dev/cciss/c0d0p1:
 Timing cached reads:   3352 MB in  2.00 seconds = 1676.70 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  100 MB in  2.59 seconds =  38.57 MB/sec

domU# hdparm -tT /dev/xvda

/dev/xvda:
 Timing cached reads:   3144 MB in  2.00 seconds = 1571.51 MB/sec
 Timing buffered disk reads:  120 MB in  3.03 seconds =  39.67 MB/sec
```

**Update:**

So it appears that this was hardware related after all. But it didn't show up until running xen. The battery was not charging ok, this led to the cache being disabled. This in combination with a VM running intensive IO led to high wait times.

Now immediately after upgrading firmware nothing had changed, but since the firmware upgrade, the battery is now charging correctly. And after the battery is fully charged, the write speeds are now acceptable, for small files the exceed those of dom0, no clue as to why that happens.

```
domU# dd if=/dev/zero of=./test1024M bs=1024k count=1024 conv=fsync
1024+0 records in
1024+0 records out
1073741824 bytes (1.1 GB) copied, 39.1087 seconds, 27.5 MB/s
```

Comment: What is the OS of the host? On the guest what is the output of `cat /sys/block/xvda/queue/scheduler`?

Comment: OS is Centos 5.5, i'll have to check the output later.

Comment: What scheduler am i supposed to use?

Comment: You are supposed to use the noop, which you are.

Comment: But this can't be expected, can it? I mean the performance is really bad. Can it have something to do with preallocated/sparse files? If i do ls on the file it reports 50GB but if i do df it only reports the part of the file that's being used, say 10GB.

Comment: This looks like a bug report for Xen/CentOS, I would take your problem to both of them and see what ideas they might have. Check against their known bugs database first.

Comment: I thought i'd try to narrow the problem down to software before reporting it as a bug. I'll order a new battery for the cache module before reporting it.

Comment: So this has been resolved. But i'll leave it up here for future reference.

Comment: So didn't your RAID controller raise some kind of alarm?

Comment: It did during POST, but who watches that on a server in an off-limits server room? :) The company i work for doesnt have ILO licenses either. It wasn't until I started fiddling with the firmware that I noticed really. It was a fun excercise though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would blame it on the old xen-version used on your host (CentOS 5.5).
I can really recommend using SLES 10 or 11. 11 has XEN 4.x built in.

I have no performance issues with my CentOS 5 DomUs running on SLES 10 Dom0s.